# Checking if List contains all items from another list

Tags: python, algorithm

What is the easiest/fastest way to check if a list of tuples contains all the the tuples that another list does. For example:

```
t1 = [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10), (11,12) ]
t2 = [ (3,4), (11,12) ]
```

would be a true case since t1 contains all the tuples in t2. I tried something like:

```
[i for e in t2 for i in t1 if e in i]
sorted(t1) == sorted(t2)
```

but this seemed to always return true. Is there a better way?

Comment: research and use sets

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `set`s

```
t1 = [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10), (11,12) ]
t2 = [ (3,4), (11,12) ]
set(t2).issubset(t1)
# returns true

# or equivalent use '<=' so
set(t2) <= set(t1)
# returns true
```

Answer (score 9):

For simplicity, you could do this:

```
print all(x in t1 for x in t2)
```

However, that's going to search through `t1` for each element in `t2`. That probably doesn't matter when `t1` is small as in this case, but to allow for larger collections I would do this:

```
s1 = set(t1)
print all(x in s1 for x in t2)
```

or this:

```
print set(t1).issuperset(t2)
```

This will generally be faster, since `in` is much faster for sets than for large lists. There's no major performance benefit in converting `t2` to a set, regardless of size, so I wouldn't.

As always, it's better if you get your data in the "right" collection to begin with. So if the main purpose of `t1` is to look things up in it, use a `set` in the first place rather than a list.

Answer (score 4):

You can create `set`s from those lists and use `issubset` method:

```
>>> t1 = [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10), (11,12) ]
>>> t2 = [ (3,4), (11,12) ]
>>> s1 = set(t1)
>>> s2 = set(t2)
>>> s2.issubset(s1)
True
```