# to find a set (having copies of elements) is a subset of a bigger set in python

Tags: python, set, subset

i have 2 sets a=[3,4,5,5] b=[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
we have to find whether a is a subset of b?

```
a=[3,4,5,5] 
b=[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
if(set(a).issubset(set(b))): 
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

this code print yes as it is ignoring copies of elements, example: it considers that 5 is occuring only single time in set 'a'

I want the answer to be 'no' as b has only one 5.

Comment: 5 *is* only occurring once in set a

Comment: no, 5 is occurring twice in set a .
set a = [3,4,5,5]

Comment: lists are not sets.

Comment: Sets do not allow for duplicates

Comment: I meant list only

Comment: Except you didn't, because you explicitly convert to a `set` in `if(set(a).` and it removes duplicates

Comment: so what to do i i dont want to remove the duplicates?

Comment: Research - [Checking if List contains all items from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28567328/1324033)

Comment: Please clarify your question. You seem to be confusing lists and set, it's difficult to tell what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must do this without libraries and your lists are sorted you can perform the match using an iterator.  Progress through the second set while advancing the first one when the values are the same.  You will know that the first list is a subset of the second if you get through all of it (using the iterator)

```
def isSubset(setA,setB):
    iterA  = iter(setA)
    valueA = next(iterA,None)
    for valueB in setB:
        if valueA == valueB:
            valueA = next(iterA,None)
    return valueA is None

a=[3,4,5,5] 
b=[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(isSubset(a,b)) # False

c=[3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9]
print(isSubset(a,c)) # True  

d=[3,4,5,5,5,6,7]
print(isSubset(b,d)) # False
```

if the lists are not guaranteed to be sorted you can sort them at the begining of the function by adding:

```
setA,setB = sorted(setA),sorted(setB)
```

if you want to make this faster, you can add a condition to exit the loop as soon as the end of setA is reached or when a value in set B is greater than the current value of set A:

```
# at beginning of for loop:
if valueA is None or valueB > valueA: break
```

Answer (score 0):

5 is occuring twice in a, but once in set(a).
`set(a)=(3,4,5)` and `set(b)=(3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`, therefore the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `collections.Counter`.

```
all(v >= 0 for v in (Counter(b) - Counter(a)).values())
```

This is True if a is a sub bag of b.

Comment: Or just `not Counter(a) - Counter(b)`.