# Python - function find list in list

Tags: python

I wrote the function to find list A is in List B, the code as below:

```
def isinlist(l1,l2):
    flag=1
    for i in range(0,len(l1)+1):
        if l1[i] not in l2:
            flag = 0
    return flag
a1 = ['hello','hi','123']
a2 = ['no worry','hello','hi','123'' ]# f1 = isinlist() 
print(isinlist(a1,a2))
```

it show the error as below

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I thought the error come from l1 and l2 wasn't defined range in the function? Can someone help advise on this ?

Comment: why do you do `len(l1)+1`? why are you putting +1?

Comment: Does the order of the elements matter? Do you consider the repeated elements?

Comment: Why not just `for x in l1: if x not in l2`? Why even bother with indexes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if List contains all items from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28567328/6045800)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `+1` from `for i in range(0,len(l1)+1):` and you are good to go:

```
def isinlist(l1,l2):
    flag=1
    for i in range(0,len(l1)):
        if l1[i] not in l2:
            flag = 0
    return flag

a1 = ['hello','hi','123']
a2 = ['no worry','hello','hi','123' ] 
print(isinlist(a1,a2))
```

To find elements in `list2` that are not in `list1`:

```
def contains(l1, l2):
    not_in__list_value=[]
    for i in range(len(l2)-len(l1)+1):
        for j in range(len(l1)):
            if l2[i+j] != l1[j]:
                not_in__list_value.append(l2[i+j] )
                break
        else:
            return not_in__list_value
    return not_in__list_value
a1 = ['hello','hi','123']
a2 = ['no worry','hello','hi','123' ]
f1 = contains(a1,a2)  
print("value that not in list1 ",f1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get already gives you a hint what is going wrong. Simply remove the `+1` in `range(0, len(l1)+1)`. Otherwise the function tries to access an index in the array, which is not defined.

```
def isinlist(l1,l2):
    flag=1
    for i in range(0,len(l1)):
        if l1[i] not in l2:
            flag = 0
    return flag
```

or what I would prefer (since `range()` starts at 0 from default)

```
def isinlist(l1,l2):
    flag=1
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        if l1[i] not in l2:
            flag = 0
    return flag
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue id in the line

```
for i in range(0,len(l1)+1):
```

in this loop `i` will eventually be larger than the length of l1 and thus `l1[i]` will be out of range

instead use

```
for i in range(len(l1)):
```

(`range()` starts at 0 by default)

Comment: thank you for correcting me  , forgot list start from 0 to n-1 :D

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that previous answers were not really pythonic and also checking only the presence of the elements.

Since you are learning python you definitely need to see how a pythonic solution would look like:

```
def is_in_list(left, right):
    """Returns true if all elements of left list are present also on right"""
    return set(left).issubset(set(right))
```

Please note that we are using `snake_case` to separate words and also the super power of *sets*.

Another pythonic way to achieve this, suggested by @Tomerikoo, which is more memory efficient:

```
def is_in_list(left, right):
    """Returns true if all elements of left list are present also on right"""
    return all(x in right for x in left).
```

Comment: Or simply `all(x in l2 for x in l1)`

Comment: So true. "Simple is better than complex"

Comment: I wasn't sure if to mention it in the comment because I'm not completely sure it's true, but I think it is also more efficient than the set. It only iterates on `l1` once (or even less if there's short-circuiting) and no extra memory. You create two sets which means iterating over both of them and assigning memory for the sets

Comment: I can say that the _set_ version has the downside of duplicating both list elements in the new sets but it has a performance upside, since it avoids checking repeated elements. Think ["a", "a", "a"] in ["a", "b", "c"].
Anyway, for the learning opportunity both (there may be more) solutions worth to be noted.

Comment: I agree. Feel free to add it to your answer :) I'm not going to post it